# How to use assert with fopen in C?

Tags: c, fopen, assert

I have a task and I need your advice

I run my program with arguments, like

```
./program.x input.txt output.txt
```

So in my program I check that I use properly arguments

```
    if (argc != 3) {                                
    printf("Wrong arguments number\n");
    printf("I should run this way:\n");
    printf("%s source result\n",argv[0]);
    exit(1);
    }

    if( (wz= fopen(argv[1],"r")) == NULL) {
        printf("Open error %s\n", argv[1]);
        exit(1);
    }

    if( (wc= fopen(argv[2],"w")) == NULL) {
        printf("Open error %s\n", argv[2]);
        exit(2);
    }
```

I also use assert to check that file is ok, they told us that we must use assert too

```
    assert((wz = fopen(argv[1] ,"r")));
    assert((wc = fopen(argv[2] ,"w")));
```

But I dont know I should first put assert, or first checking number of arguments?

```
    if (argc != 3) {                                
    printf("Wrong arguments number\n");
    printf("I should run this way:\n");
    printf("%s source result\n",argv[0]);
    exit(1);
    }

    if( (wz= fopen(argv[1],"r")) == NULL) {
        printf("Open error %s\n", argv[1]);
        exit(1);
    }

    if( (wc= fopen(argv[2],"w")) == NULL) {
        printf("Open error %s\n", argv[2]);
        exit(2);
    }
    assert((wz = fopen(argv[1] ,"r")));
    assert((wc = fopen(argv[2] ,"w")));
```

or

```
    if (argc != 3) {                                
    printf("Wrong arguments number\n");
    printf("I should run this way:\n");
    printf("%s source result\n",argv[0]);
    exit(1);
    }

    if( (wz= fopen(argv[1],"r")) == NULL) {
        printf("Open error %s\n", argv[1]);
        exit(1);
    }

    if( (wc= fopen(argv[2],"w")) == NULL) {
        printf("Open error %s\n", argv[2]);
        exit(2);
    }
    assert((wz = fopen(argv[1] ,"r")));
    assert((wc = fopen(argv[2] ,"w")));
    if (argc != 3) {                                
    printf("Wrong arguments number\n");
    printf("I should run this way:\n");
    printf("%s source result\n",argv[0]);
    exit(1);
    }

    if( (wz= fopen(argv[1],"r")) == NULL) {
        printf("Open error %s\n", argv[1]);
        exit(1);
    }

    if( (wc= fopen(argv[2],"w")) == NULL) {
        printf("Open error %s\n", argv[2]);
        exit(2);
    }
```

Comment: Do not use `assert` with `fopen`.

Comment: You should not call `assert` with any expression that has side effects, because it won't generate any code at all if the `NDEBUG` macro is defined.

Comment: Generally asserts are for debug builds, so you should not use them for flow control in your actual program... that is a tradition that you can break because it requires compiling with the macro NDEBUG for release build ... but the fact that they are conditionally ignored means you should not use them for business logic, it will bite you somewhere down the road.

Answer (score 1):

`assert(expression)` is a macro defined by `#include <assert.h>`.

If the `NDEBUG` macro is defined before the `#include <assert.h>` line then the macro call `assert(expression)` expands to the void expression `((void)0)`. Otherwise, it will write an error message to the standard error stream and call `abort()`.

Because `assert(expression)` might not generate any code, it should not be called if the `expression` has any side effects. One example of a side effect is assigning a value to a variable (or other lvalue). Another example of a side effect is opening file. The call `assert((wz = fopen(argv[1] ,"r")));` does both of those things. The correct way to use `assert` in this case, is to do perform the operation before the `assert` call and only use `assert` to check the result. For example:

```
wz = fopen(argv[1], "r");
assert(wz != NULL);
```

The expression `wz != NULL` has no side effects (assuming `wz` has not been declared with the `volatile` type qualifier), so is safe.

---

OP is using `assert` as part of an exercise.  It should be noted that `assert` is typically used only to check things that are not expected to fail, and the message it writes to the standard error stream is meant to help the developer discover bugs in the code. However, calling `fopen` on a command line argument is something that is quite likely to fail, and should normally be handled in a way that is useful to the *user* of the program, rather than the developer.